# Iterating through NSSet, extracting arrays

Tags: xcode, for-loop, ios7, nsarray, nsset

I have two entities tied together with a to-many relationship; A dish has a to-many relationship with ingredients and ingredients has a to-one relationship with a dish.

I acces the ingredients for a given dish in my collectionViewController like so:

```
Dish *dish = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"%@", [dish.ingredients valueForKey:@"ingredientName"]);
```

this returns the following:

```
{(
    flormelis,
    "ristede og afskallede hasseln\U00f8dder",
    glucose,
    "ristede mandler",
    honnig,
    "hvid chokolade",
    "pasteuriseret \U00e6ggehvide",
    "sukker (35g + 180g)",
    vand
)}
{(
    flormelis,
    "ristede og afskallede hasseln\U00f8dder",
    glucose,
    "ristede mandler",
    honnig,
    "hvid chokolade",
    "pasteuriseret \U00e6ggehvide",
    "sukker (35g + 180g)",
    vand
)}
{(
    "\U00e6ggehvider",
    hvedemel,
    sukker,
    "mandler (blendet)",
    flormelis
)}
```

From what I can see, that is an array within a dictionary.
What I want to do is to populate each collectionView cell (which in my app is a dish) with the ingredients for that specific dish.

And now to my problem:

The strings in the array are not encoded (hence the /U00e6 etc. etc.), so I need to loop through them with a for loop and return them as a string so they get formatted correctly, and then store them in an array and populate my ingredients label with that array data, but I can't seem to figure out how... I've tried a for loop that accepts an array and returns a string, but that obviously just returns all the ingredients as strings for all the dishes, and thats obv not what I want.

I think I need a for loop that first seperates the ingredients into separate arrays, and then send that array to another for loop to return the formatted strings?

I might be trying to solve this problem in a cumbersome way, so if you have a better solution, feel free to suggest it!

Thanks in advance
Chris